# Add authors as footnote in lncs

Tags: footnotes, lncs

please, I was asked to modify the .tex file of a manuscript. The problem is that I want to add "supervised by ..." as a footnote and when use \footnote{supervised by ...} in \author{} it does not work. I use a Latex lncs format. Thank you!

Comment: It's been a while since I last used it, but doesn't `llncs` put the author name in the left-hand page header? Thus, a footnote might not give you what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is using `\thanks`, not `\footnote`:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\title{LaTeX Template for Your LNCS Paper}

\author{Author 1\thanks{Supervised by Author 9}, Author 2}

\institute{Lab, University, Address}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction}

The rest goes here.

\kant

\end{document}
```

I added also the `runningheads` option just to show that the headline containing the authors' names is not influenced by the presence of `\thanks`.

**First page**

[image: Page 1]

**Second page**

[image]

Comment: is there a way to state the same `\thanks{}` for two authors? for instance, if both authors were supervised by *Prof X*?

Comment: @beta It can be done, with acrobatics. I don't think this information should go in the “thanks” part anyway.

Comment: I need it for stating that two authors contributed equally to a paper. see here for instance: http://www.jbc.org/content/early/2012/01/18/jbc.M111.263434.full.pdf

Comment: @beta Please, make it into a fresh question

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287059/springer-lncs-template-same-footnote-for-two-authors

Answer (score 0):

You might want to `\protect` the `\footnote` command. This one worked for me:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\title{LaTeX Template for Your LNCS Paper}

\author{Author 1\protect\footnote{Supervised by Author 9}, Author 2}

\institute{Lab, University, Address}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction}

The rest goes here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works but I used \thanks{} it has the same effect as a footnote I think. With your solution I got ** instead of *.