# Springer LNCS Template: Same footnote for two authors

Tags: footnotes, lncs

To add footnotes to authors in the Springer LNCS template one should not use `\footnote{}`, but `\thanks{}`.

Source Code:

```
\author{Author 1\thanks{author footnote...}}
```

This results in the author looking like this:

[image]

And the footnote looking like this:

[image]

However, I would like to use the same footnote for two authors. My first try did not work:

```
\author{Author 1\thanks{author footnote...}
\and Author 2\thanks{author footnote...}}
```

This obviously creates another (second) footnote, just with the same text, looking like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I create one author footnote which is referred to by two different authors?

Comment: Why not simply leave out the `thanks` for the first author and imply that the footnote concerns both authors?

Comment: no the best solution, imo... footnotes should be explicit and not implying something.

Comment: If you are using this template because you are submitting something to one of Elseiver's journal, just copy and paste two times the same `\thanks` command: it's their problem to adapt the layout, not yours. They might have special macros to handle this case, but could not spot it if you use a circumvent way not to duplicate this command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the lack of a MWE this is a quick and dirty solution using the `article` class …

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\repeatthanks}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnote}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author1\thanks{Text}, Author2\repeatthanks}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It will only work if there’s no other `\thanks` in between.

Answer (score 4):

The `llncs` class treats `\thanks` differently from the standard classes. But some tricks make the thing possible.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\repthanks}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\def\thanks}
  {\let\repthanks\repthanksunskip\def\thanks}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\def\thanks}
  {\let\repthanks\@gobble\def\thanks}
  {}{}
\newcommand\repthanksunskip[1]{\unskip{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{LaTeX Template for Your LNCS Paper}

\author{Author 1\thanks{Supervised by Author 9\protect\label{X}}, Author 2\repthanks{X}}

\institute{Lab, University, Address}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction}

The rest goes here.

\kant

\end{document}
```

You need to do `\protect\label{<whatever>}` in the `\thanks` command you want to repeat and `\repthanks{<whatever>}` for repeating the footnote marker.

A similar adjustment could be made, if necessary, also for the `\institute` part.

[image]